# Script Page Load / Chrome's finish

Tags: google-chrome, pageload

I'm looking for a way to get the page load of a website.

Namely the "finish" value from chrome network tab:

[image]

I want to compare websites, so the value must not be exactly like in chrome, just comparable between websites.

I basically want to answer the question "How does my Page Load time compare to other websites".

I tried things like yslow.js (buggy) and tried with selenium and other headless browser but was not able to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get these metrics from `window.performance.timing`.

Here is an example with Python :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(r"http://stackoverflow.com/")

times = driver.execute_script("""
  var t = window.performance.timing; return [
    t.domContentLoadedEventEnd - t.navigationStart,
    t.loadEventEnd - t.navigationStart
  ]; """)

print "DOMContentLoaded: %s  Load: %s" % tuple(times)
```

Comment: nice code, but i have get **finish**. so please how to i am get?